# Java cannot see jlabel in jframe nor imageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm writing a simple Java code that shows a text inside a frame and substitutes the standard ImageIcon with a custom one (.png file), stored in the same directory of this Java file.
However, whenever I run the code no text appears inside the frame and I also noticed that no Image is shown as Icon.
I'm running Java on VsCode and the code is as follows:

```
public class Example{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setSize(420,420);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
     frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());

     Jlabel label = new Label();
     label.setText("Hello there!");
     frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Needless to say that I'm importing javax.swing.ImageIcon, javax.swing.JFrame and javax.swing.JLabel.

Whenever I run the above code this is the frame that appears:
[image]

May this be a problem due to Virtualization not being set on on my computer?

Comment: @user15358848 Thanks! It's embarassing to admit, but I didn't add it to the frame

Comment: @user15358848 regarding the ImageIcon. It does actually find the file in the directory , still though it doesn't show it